# Windows Live Mail - XOAUTH2 authentication failed

Tags: windows-7, imap, windows-live-mail

2 days ago, I was suddenly unable to access **Hotmail** using **Windows Live Mail** with **IMAP**.

What change did Microsoft make to its **IMAP** server 2 days ago?

.

*Background* -

For the last 2 days, I cannot sign-in to Hotmail using the Windows Live Mail program (WLM) with IMAP in Windows 7. WLM is part of the *Windows Essentials* suite of software, which is an option to install locally on a Windows 7 computer.

By going to www.Outlook.com (in my web browser) I can still sign-in to my Hotmail account. But using the WLM desktop app, I now get the following 0x800CCC0F error:

**XOAUTH2 authentication failed. None of the authentication methods supported by your IMAP server are supported on this computer.**

How do I reconnect my Hotmail account to Windows Live Mail, which was working fine until 2 days ago ?

I need WLM, because it provides local storage (in my computer) for my e-mails, which web-based email (such as *Outlook on the web*) does not offer.

Answer (score 1):

I can't be 100 percent sure yet, more testing is probably in order, but the answer seems to be that the error only blocks access to the IMAP server if authentication is used.

The error message specifically refers to "authentication".

My work-around is therefore to uncheck/untick both of the settings - in the Properties of the individual email account within Windows Live Mail - that refer to authentication.

Whether this is wise, from a security perspective, is a moot point, since it's the only means of accessing the account. Therefore my working solution, subject to any other ideas posted here, is to untick 'log on using authentication' in both of the places where that option is present in the account settings.

Initial indications seem to be that this does restore access to the account in Windows Live Mail.

.

**Addendum (6 Sept 2019)** -

This is a better description of the solution -

Make the following changes:

1. Right-click on the account name in the folder pane, and select "Properties".

.

2. On the "Servers" tab:

a. Change the incoming (IMAP) server name to either imap-mail.outlook.com or outlook.office365.com

b. Ensure that the Email username is your full e-mail address

c. Ensure that "Log on using clear text authentication" is selected

d. Ensure that "My server requires authentication" is selected

.

3. On the Advanced tab:

a. Ensure that "This server requires a secure connection (SSL)" is selected for both incoming *and* outgoing mail

b. Ensure that the server port for incoming mail is 993

.

4. Click "Apply" then "OK".

If you had "Log on using Secure Password Authentication" before, that was the source of your troubles. Few public mail servers support or require it. Your password is still safe, because it's passed through a secure TLS tunnel by virtue of your selecting "This server requires a secure connection (SSL)" on the Advanced tab.